# javascript select the part of a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<li class="workorder" id="workorder_7">
```

I would like to use the digit after the _ in some javascript.
In this case, I need the integer 7

How would I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that: regular expressions, substring matching, and others. One of the easiest is to just use `split` to break the string into an array, and grab the last array element:

```
var str_id = "workorder_7";
var id = str_id.split('_')[1];
```

You can also use `.pop` as suggested by VisioN to get the last element from the array. Then it would work with a string with any number of underscores, provided the numeric id is the last one:

```
var str_id = "main_workorder_7";
var id = str_id.split('_').pop();
```

Comment: @dfsq I'm assuming OP is using a fixed format for the id attributes. But if it's not fixed, you can always assign the return from split in a var and use `.length-1` as the index.

Comment: I'd better use `.split("_").pop()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `substring`:

```
var str_id = "workorder_7";
var id = str_id.substring(str_id.indexOf('_') + 1);
```

If you want to get the content following the *last* underscore, you can use:

```
var str_id = "work_order_id_7";
var id = str_id.substring(str_id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```